# How to change border colour in Aurelia Dialog?

Tags: css, dialog, border, aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I have a dialog as you can see here:

```
<template >
      <ux-dialog >
        <ux-dialog-body>
          <div t="logbook.delete-logs">Möchten Sie alle Logbücher löschen?</div>
        </ux-dialog-body>

        <ux-dialog-footer>
          <button attach-focus="true" click.trigger="controller.cancel()" t="logbook.cancel">Abbrechen</button>
          <button click.trigger="controller.ok()" t="logbook.ok">Ok</button>
        </ux-dialog-footer>
      </ux-dialog>
</template>
```

and related view-model:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection'
import { DialogController } from 'aurelia-dialog'

@inject(DialogController)
export class DeleteLogbook {
  public controller: DialogController

  constructor (controller: DialogController) {
    this.controller = controller
  }
}
```

I want to change the colour of dialog's border.
I want to use Aurelia concept for this purpose. Could you please tell me the solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should show a little more research. Try targetting the `ux-dialog` element in your CSS for example.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jesse suggested in his comment, you can override the styles of certain elements.

in this case, you simply add the following to your stylesheet

```
ux-dialog {
    border: 5px solid #fff700;
}
```

however one thing to note is that, if you are to load the stylesheet containing the above in your aurelia `main` which is very common (or in any other way before loading `aurelia-dialog`), you will have to add `!important` to your styles.

```
ux-dialog {
    border: 5px solid #fff700 !important;
}
```

it's because the actual package is been loaded after your own styles and they will naturally override yours.

however, it's better to load your styles in `app` or by component (such as each component having it's own stylesheet) to avoid `!important` in your styles

Comment: Please avoid the use of `!important` whenever you can. In my app, i've simply loaded the css in `app.html` using `<require from="dialogs/dialog.css"></require>`, which works fine.